# MYSQL query enhancement to get correct results

Tags: php, mysql

I have Table "users":

```
+------+---------+  
| name | company |  
+------+---------+  
| John | a1a2a3  |  
| Mike | a10     |  
| Gorg | a3      |  
| Mary | a11     |  
+------+---------+
```

And I am trying the following select query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE company LIKE '%a1%'
```

Which results:

```
+------+---------+  
| name | company |  
+------+---------+  
| John | a1a2a3  |  
| Mike | a10     |  
| Mary | a11     |  
+------+---------+
```

While I need only to have:

```
+------+---------+  
| name | company |  
+------+---------+  
| John | a1a2a3  |  
+------+---------+
```

Comment: They all contain a1.. So it's logical that you get that result.. You only want the first one? Or what do you exactly want?

Comment: Yes I need only a1 
not a11 or a12

Comment: So specifically, you want `a1` followed _not_ by another number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE company LIKE '%a1a%' or company LIKE '%a1'
```

Comment: I think the example of `a1a2a3` is too specific, and not to be taken literally...

Comment: @xyro you don't need something more generalized than the pattern `aNa`?  What about `a1b`?

Comment: @MichaelBerlowsky: if the pattern is what he has written on his example I think the query will work for him; but just if this is the exact pattern

Answer (score 1):

From the [man page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html), how about something like this?

`SELECT company REGEXP 'a1[^0-9]+';`